# Segmentation fault when trying Project Euler #14

Tags: c, memoization

This is the problem: https://projecteuler.net/problem=14

Please don't give me the solution. Just tell me where am I going wrong. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Collatz_Count(int n);

int cache [10000000] = {0};
int main(void)
{
    int n, answer, count = 0;

    for (n = 1; n < 1000000; ++n)
    {
        if (Collatz_Count(n) > count)
        {
            count = Collatz_Count(n);
            answer = n;
        }
    }

    printf("The number is %d and the count is %d\n", answer, count);

    return 0;
}

int Collatz_Count(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (n < 1000000)
    {
        if (cache[n] != 0)
        {
            return cache[n];
        }
        else
        {
            if ((n % 2) == 0)
            {
                cache[n] = (1 + Collatz_Count(n / 2));
            }
            else
            {
                cache[n] = (1 + Collatz_Count(3 * n + 1));
            }

            return cache[n];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ((n % 2) == 0)
        {
            return (1 + Collatz_Count(n / 2));
        }
        else
        {
            return (1 + Collatz_Count(3 * n + 1));
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting "Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)" when executing the program. I just learnt memoization and wanted to apply it.

I tried setting 'n < 100000' and it worked properly but not when 'n < 1000000'.

I am really sorry for the lack of comments.

Comment: Wiithout running it, I guess there is some number in the sequence that is beyond the length of `cache[]`.

Comment: You are also calling `Collatz_Count` **twice** for some numbers - could this be a problem? Try assigning the return value to a temp variable, comparing that, then using that in the `if` block.

Comment: Another possibility is that one of the sequences is long enough to cause a stack overflow during recursion.

Comment: Note that the maximum number from the Collatz sequence for 487039 (as one example) is 24,648,077,896, and it takes 381 steps to get to 1.  The maximum value for any Collatz sequence starting from a number between 1 and 1,000,000 is `o = 704511 m = 56991483520 c = 242`; the maximum number of steps is for `o = 837799 m = 2974984576 c = 524`.  Those maxima do not fit into 32-bit numbers; you must use 64-bits for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran the program using gdb. The issue is that the argument to `Collatz_Count` eventually exceeds the valid range of integers, which is undefined behaviour.

Many compilers wrap around to negative numbers when such an overflow happens, and then trying to access `cache` with a negative index gives a segmentation fault.

Replacing `int` with `long long` should fix the issue.

Comment: Strictly, `long` can be a 32-bit value and using `long long` (which must be at least 64-bits) is a better choice.